# Error al intentar ejecutar sentencia SQL, System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en C# para recuperar datos de una base de datos. El caso es: cuando intenta ejecutar la sentencia me sale este error:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: Fill: la propiedad SelectCommand.Connection no se ha inicializado".

Entiendo básicamente que no está inicializada dicha propiedad, pero... ¿cómo hacer en mi caso? Les dejo mi código:

```
    String consulta;
    Boolean estado;

    public frmListadoDeInterno()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        consulta = "";
        estado = false;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        validarCbo();

       if (estado == true) {

            if (cboSucursales.SelectedItem.Equals("Casa Matriz"))
            {
                consultaMatriz();
            }

            if (cboSucursales.SelectedItem.Equals("San Lorenzo"))
            {
                consultaSanLorenzo();
            }

            if (cboSucursales.SelectedItem.Equals("Mariano Roque Alonso"))
            {
                consultaMariano();
            }

            if (cboSucursales.SelectedItem.Equals("Todos"))
            {
                consultaTodos();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No has precionado en el botón conectar.");
        }
    }

    private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void frmListadoDeInterno_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        desconectarBaseDeDatos();
        Close();
    }

    private void btnConectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conectarBaseDeDatos();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fallo al conectar. A continuación se detalla el error: " + ex);
        }

    }

    private void conectarBaseDeDatos()
    {
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conexion = new NpgsqlConnection(
                  "Server = localhost;" 
                + "Port = 5432;" 
                + "User Id = postgres;" 
                + "Password = postgres;"
                + "Database = repuestos;");
            conexion.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Conectado.");
            estado = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al conectar. A continuación se detalla el error: " + ex);
        }


    }

    private void desconectarBaseDeDatos()
    {

        NpgsqlConnection conexion = new NpgsqlConnection(builder.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("Desconectado.");
        conexion.Close();
        estado = false;
    }   

    private void consultaMatriz()
    {
        try
        {
            NpgsqlCommand con = new NpgsqlCommand();
            consulta = "SELECT * FROM personas;";
            con.CommandText = consulta;
            NpgsqlDataAdapter adapt = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(con);
            DataSet dset = new DataSet();
            adapt.Fill(dset, "personas"); // El error apunta a esta línea.
            dgvRegListado.DataSource = dset.Tables["personas"];

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

        }
    }
    private void consultaSanLorenzo()
    {

    }
    private void consultaMariano()
    {

    }
    private void consultaTodos()
    {

    }
    private void validarCbo()
    {
        if (cboSucursales.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("¡Debe seleccionar una opción!");
            cboSucursales.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void dgvRegListado_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Pero no estas utilizando SQL Server  verdad?

Comment: Así mismo, estoy usando Postgres SQL. Si sirve como plus, estos son los using que he utilizado: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Npgsql;

Comment: ¿El error te ocurre en `consultaMatriz` o dónde?

Comment: Por lo que veo. ya que no tengo Postgrees acá. Es que estas abriendo la conexión y se la pasa al command pero estar en métodos diferentes y probablemente por ser privados, el objeto conection se cierra ya que lo afecta el ámbito. Sugiero que lo haga en un solo metodo y usando instrucciones Using.

Comment: Exacto amigo, en ese método ocurre el problema, justamente dejé un comentario (en el código) en qué línea dice que está mal. La idea es que: al ejecutarse ese método (consultaMatriz) me recupere los datos que pido mediante esa sentencia.

Comment: Entonces... si mal no entendí; todas mis operaciones de conexión, desconexión, consultas. Las realizo en un solo método. ¿Qué pasa si pongo en public mis métodos? ¿Cambiaría el resultado? Es solo a modo de consulta.

Comment: @julioAgustin, pueden seguir siendo privadas pero lo puede mandar como un parámetro. Pero ya tiene su respuesta Davilo lo hizo.

Comment: Perfecto, voy a probar esa solución. Gracias...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo sería necesario realizar:

```
var connStr = "Server = localhost;Port = 5432;User Id = postgres;Password = postgres;Database = repuestos;";
var query = "SELECT * FROM personas;";

var dset = new DataSet();

using(var adapt = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(query, connStr)){
    adapt.Fill(dset, "personas")
}

dgvRegListado.DataSource = dset.Tables["personas"];
```

Donde, el constructor tiene una opción de solo poder indicarle la cadena de conexión:

```
public NpgsqlDataAdapter(string selectCommandText, string selectConnectionString)
```

---

Si quieres usar `NpgsqlConnection` podrías hacer:

```
var connStr = "Server = localhost;Port = 5432;User Id = postgres;Password = postgres;Database = repuestos;";
var query = "SELECT * FROM personas;";

var dset = new DataSet();

using(var cnBD = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr)){
    using(var adapt = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(query, cnBD)){
        adapt.Fill(dset, "personas")
    }
}

dgvRegListado.DataSource = dset.Tables["personas"];
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [NpgsqlDataAdapter(String, String)](http://www.npgsql.org/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter.html)
- [Referencia de código: NpgsqlDataAdapter(String, String)](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/77a597d22a2b435d7994e871265955e57036f166/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlDataAdapter.cs/#L91)